# Declaring numpy arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to create a numpy array in python but I am getting an error as shown below
i tried same as in a tutorial but still the error is coming
What's the problem?

```
a=np.array([1,2,3])

print(a)
```

---

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> ----> 1 a=np.array([1,2,3])
> 2 print(a)
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Your code works on my machine (when I `import numpy as np`). Output is `[1, 2, 3]`, as expected. What version of python and numpy are you using ? You can check the numpy version with `print(np.__version__)`, and python version on a terminal with `python --version`

Comment: I have a feeling you may have defined `np.array = [1,2,3]` at some point, or something similar. Do you run any other code beside what you have shown? At least your code sample is lacking the corresponding imports, which might indicate where the problem lies. Also: Do you work in a jupyter notebook?

Comment: There is code before this that is causing an error, probably because you've overwritten some built-in functionality.

Comment: @André  Thank you i did "factory reset runtime" in google collab notebooks now the code is working

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are overwriting np.
This is how it works:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2,3])
print(a)
```